# A function to format numbers as written in Germany

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing my first script for an invoice template based on a Google Doc.
It works fine. I need to use it in Germany so I need to be able to format the prices in the way they are shown in Germany.

I have written a short function to do this but am interested in whether there is a better or more obvious way of achieving this.

```
// this formats numbers as used in Germany
function numberToGerman(number){
  number = Utilities.formatString("%d.%d,%02d", number/1000, number%1000, number%1*100);
  return number;
}
```

It has a problem above 999.999,99 or below 1.000,00 at the moment but I hope there is a better solution out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a slight modification of the [answer by Elias Zamaria](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901298), replacing separators and ensuring exactly two decimals:

```
function numberToGerman(number){
  var parts = number.toString().split(".");
  parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
  parts[1] = ((parts[1] || "") + "00").slice(0,2);  
  return parts.join(",");
}
```

The parts are the integer and fractional parts. Groups of three digits are processed by the regex, which places dots accordingly. The fractional parts is expanded/truncated to two places.

#### Remarks

1. Unfortunately, `number.toLocaleString("de-DE")` is not yet supported by Google Apps Script. One can use `number.toLocaleString()` but then the performance depends on someone having set the correct locale. Also, [options concerning decimal places](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) aren't supported either, so this doesn't help that much.
2. If this was to be used in a spreadsheet, you can apply appropriate formatting to cells either manually from the menu, or from a script: for example `cell.setNumberFormat("#,###.00")`. This looks like U.S.-style formatting, but once the locale of the spreadsheet is changed to Germany, it changes accordingly, e.g. 1.234.567,89.

Comment: The function works perfectly and produces exactly the result I was hoping for. I nearly understand most of it. :-) Thank you for the help. Call me up for a beer next time you are skiing the Alps :-)

Comment: I have been using the function since it was suggested and it works exactly as hoped.
Today I had to add an extra line at the top so that it would work as expected even when I passed a value of 121.399999 to it.
I know I could round before calling the function but this seemed "safer".

I added  number = number.toFixed(2);